# How can I combine multiple update statements with django?

Tags: mysql, django, sql-update

So I am new at database stuff and am working on a hobby project. Looking at the poll tutorial on the django website:

Lets say that I have a particularly popular poll that is slowing down my database. Every vote is incrementing a choice by 1. Wouldn't it make more sense to collect all of the votes in the past minute or so and combine it into a single update that increments the vote amount by how many votes occurred in the last minute?

It feels silly to have an db update on every click.

Does this make sense? If it does, how can I do it?

Comment: The question becomes, where would you store all the votes if not in the database?

Comment: @burhan OK fair enough. Perhaps in the process memory (preferred)? Maybe in memcached? Obviously by the definition of the problem, i'm imagining a situation where accurate counts aren't as important as fast counts, so losing some votes is OK.

Answer (score 0):

QuerySet has an [update method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) which you can use to perform an UPDATE on the filtered rows, something like eg. this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(anyattribute__in=['one', 'two']).update(otherattribute='something')
```

Comment: Right, but how do I batch up queries and not run this on every request?